# How can I JOIN two tables, but only include each row from the right table once?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with some tables, which I want to join, but though there will be multiple matches, want the budgets table rows to only appear next to the first row with which they match, to allow me to sum the budgets after the group by without duplicating the same budget.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT categories.categoryId), 
GROUP_CONCAT(budgets.budget) FROM transactions
    JOIN categories ON transactions.categoryId = categories.categoryId
    JOIN budgets ON transactions.categoryId = budgets.categoryId
    WHERE transactions.userId = 1 AND transactions.date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -30 DAY) AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY categories.displayName
```

Essentially, I want the GROUP_CONCAT(budgets.budget) column to return 204, 209, 206; and not 204, 204, 209, 206

I'm using this as a workaround using 2 queries if that is any help:

```
SELECT SUM(transactions.amount) AS spend, categories.displayName, 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT categories.categoryId) AS id FROM transactions
JOIN categories ON transactions.categoryId = categories.categoryId
WHERE transactions.userId = ${req.params.id} AND transactions.date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -30 DAY) AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY categories.displayName

SELECT SUM(budgets.budget) AS budget, categories.displayName, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT categories.categoryId) FROM budgets 
JOIN categories ON categories.categoryId = budgets.categoryId
WHERE budgets.userId = ${req.params.id}
GROUP BY categories.displayName


res1.forEach((group, key) => {
  res2.forEach((result) => {
    if (result.displayName === group.displayName) {
      res1[key].budget = result.budget;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Link some sample data via a SQL Playground tool such as rextester. Hard to visualise without some data.

Comment: @JGFMK not sure if this is quite what you were after but i've put a stripped down dump of the database?? https://rextester.com/EVLF80683

Comment: Link it when there are no syntax errors and try again.. Users is missing as table. Insert in transactions is not closed correctly.

Comment: @JGFMK Ok, I think this is better now: https://rextester.com/VKVWK40430 also I'll update my question with some code that I'm using as a workaround to achieve this with two queries - I'd still be interested to know if it can be done with the one SQL query :)